# Display an Amazon s3 image with https request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image, amazon-s3

I have an image fetching "dynamically" from amazon s3 bucket, here is the source example:
src =  http://s3.amazonaws.com/kidslink_assets/logos/5082f5d279216d14d000001e/original.png?1350759890

i need this to be a http*s* (https) request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood S3 terminology, S3 response always serve as https . I tried to access your image using http, that's default redirecting to https (https://s3.amazonaws.com/kidslink_assets/logos/5082f5d279216d14d000001e/original.png?1350759890)

So you not need to worry about https/ssl.

Answer (score 0):

As client needs to see it as https request, i added manually when the page is rendering the image. I means added "s" manually for the link before rendering the page as http and https are doing the same.